# Designing c# class from json template

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have to design a class based on a json template that i received. I'm stuck at this part of the json:

```
events: {
    "door": [
        5,
        {
            valueone: 27,
            valuetwo: "something"
        }
    ],
    "window": [
        2,
        {
            valueone: 13,
            valuetwo: "something"
        }
    ]
}
```

The best i can come up with is this property in the root object:

```
public Dictionary<string, EventData> Events { get; set; }
```

Where Events is defined like this:

```
public class EventData
{
    public int valueone { get; set; }
    public string valuetwo { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me for example the following output:

```
Events: {
    door: {
        valueone: 27,
        valuetwo: "something"
    }
}
```

But i have no idea how to design the class to get the numbers in the json example (5 and 2) in the output. I have tried to google for this for a long time today but i'm not quite sure what to search for.

Comment: Try http://json2csharp.com/, paste your valid JSON and you can get your class template

Answer (score 0):

Below is an outline of the code that would fit:

```
public class Event
{
    public List<Elements> door { get; set; }
    public List<Elements> window { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Elements
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public IDictionary<string, string> Values { get; set;}
}
```

You could build your objects with C# then use JSON.Net to serialise them to there JSON counterpart using:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YOUR-OBJECT-HERE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you don't necessarily have to define types for capturing json like that:

For parsing you can use `dynamic` to capture the json as parsed by some json libararies.

For serializing json you can define anonymous objects like so

```
Json.Stringify(new {
    events = new {
        door = new[] {
            5,
            new { ... }
        }
    }
});
```

If you *do* need to define explicit types (because you want a model in your c# program) you may want to get more clarity about the domain that you are about to model. You can mirror the same JSON with different C# structures, so what really matters here is what the business/requirements do or will look like.

As @Habib noted in his comment you can use `json2csharp.com` to give you a hint (I did not know of that service until now - looks interesting!), but json2csharp.com will not be able to answer those questions.

Note: The "json" as it stands in your question is not valid JSON.